# Alter Background image of a html lable with Jscript onChange event

Tags: html, css, onchange, jscript

Why Does This Not Work, i get url not defined.. Any1 have any ideas how to fix this.

i want the chosen file image to populate the labals image and display there but it wont do it.

Iv Tried the allready Suggested methods of this question but i cannot get it working with such suggestions.

```
<div class='bigimage'>
    <label id='img00' style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-image:url('<?php echo $i0url ?>'); background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;" >
        <input type='file'  id='sellimage1' name='sellimage1'  style='display:none;' onchange='addimg0(this);' accept='image/*' required />
    </label>        
</div>

<script>
function addimg0(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById('img00').style.backgroundImage=url(e.target.result);   

            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code should be properly indented and you should accept the edits if someone has done for you.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to add `""` to `url` of `background-image`**

```
 document.getElementById('img00').style.backgroundImage="url("+e.target.result+")";
```

```js
function addimg0(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
       document.getElementById('img00').style.backgroundImage="url("+e.target.result+")";
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='bigimage'>
    <label id='img00' style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-image:url('<?php echo $i0url ?>'); background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;" >click here
        <input type='file'  id='sellimage1' name='sellimage1'  style='display:none;' onchange='addimg0(this);' accept='image/*' required />
    </label>        
</div>
```

Comment: @MelissaHicking tell me if that what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Your code is giving console error:

```
(index):52 Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined
    at FileReader.reader.onload ((index):52)
```

Currently you are executing url as a function and not treating it as a string. To fix that, change code for `onload` function to this:

```
document.getElementById('img00').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + e.target.result + ')';
```

You can use ES6 string literals here to construct `backgroundImage` property like so:

```
document.getElementById('img00').style.backgroundImage = `url(${e.target.result})`;
```

But you will need to add babel-plugin to transpile ES6 to ES5.